# Difference of field value between two records in same table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have table1 and it has meter reading field. I want to calculate difference between meter reading record1 and meter reading record 2.

Comment: Are you willing to use VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a contiguous `ID` field in `table1` the following query would give you the desired results:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.MeterReading, T2.MeterReading, [T2].[MeterReading]-[T1].[MeterReading] AS Difference
FROM tbl AS T1, tbl AS T2
WHERE (((T1.ID)=[T2].[ID]-1));
```

However, if `ID` is of `autonumber` type you risk missing out some numbers and losing contiguity, so I would suggest using `number` type for ID and using some code to ensure contiguity.

Comment: That is pretty unsafe if the ID is an autonumber.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed names of table and fields, so obviously you should change those to fit your schema.

```
Dim rs AS new ADODB.Recordset
Dim PrevReading AS Long

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tblReadings ORDER BY ReadingDate",CurrentProject.Connection,adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Do While Not rs.Eof
   rs.Field("Difference")=rs.Field("MeterReading") - PrevReading
   PrevReading = rs.Fields("MeterReading")
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```